# Nav Bar Scroll Function NOT Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

***What I need to do to change the colour of my nav bar when I scroll down*** by a certain amount and reset when I scroll back up. I have tried many different techniques. AKA youtube videos on the subject. But cannot seem to get it to work! I have a 'scrolled' class in my CSS stylesheet with a background color set. But it won't even take my function.

```
$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $('.nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
});
```

[Google Chrome Dev-Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCTtR.png)

Comment: did you get any error? check browser console for that and share your error

Comment: Um, I remember getting a syntax error before when I was trying to figure it out but now it is not giving any errors. Just, not working Is there a way I can check using google chrome's dev tools if it is even reading the script.js file?

Comment: all kind of js error will stated inside the console. You can use `CRTL U` to check that file is added and code is coming or not

Comment: I said check console section for error not source

Comment: No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $('.nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
//});
```

```css
.nav {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.nav.scrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
</div>
```

THANKS SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the outermost `$(function() {...` does, but I think that was the reason the snippet inside did not run.

```js
//$(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $('.nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
//});
```

```css
.nav {
  max-width: 500px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.nav.scrolled {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
</div>
```

If you intended to use IIFE, immediately invoked function expression, you can do

```
(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
            $('.nav').addClass('scrolled');
        }else {
            $('.nav').removeClass('scrolled');
        }
    });
}());
```

which also works.

Answer (score 0):

This describes how to implement this in **Vanilla JS**, also taking care of performance using **passive event listeners**.

Codepen [Links](https://codepen.io/hemantjadon/pen/MVVNOX)

```js
let navRef = document.querySelector('nav');

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  if (window.scrollY > 500) {
    navRef.classList.add('scrolled');
  } else {
    navRef.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
}, { passive: true })
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;  
}

div.container {
  background: aliceblue;
  height: 10000px;
}

nav {
  height: 50px;
  background: pink;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

nav.scrolled {
  background: #80deea;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav></nav> 
</div>
```